# Reducing Run Time C or C++

Tags: c++, compilation

Can u Guys Please give me tips on how to reduce the compilation time of my c or c++ programmes...
Some basic simple techniques will be helpful.
I was solving a question through a site(https://www.codechef.com/problems/TRISQ)
**The Question was :-**

What is the maximum number of squares of size 2x2 that can be fit in a right angled isosceles triangle of base B.One side of the square must be parallel to the base of the isosceles triangle.Base is the shortest side of the triangle.
First line contains T, the number of test cases.

Each of the following T lines contains 1 integer B.
Output exactly T lines, each line containing the required answer.

**Sample Input**

```
11
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

**Sample Output**

```
0
0
0
1
1
3
3
6
6
10
10
```

**MY CODE**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T,N,a,i,j;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
        {
            a=0;
            cin>>N;
            N=N/2;
            N--;
            j=N;
            for(i=0;i<j;i++)
                {
                    a+=N;
                    N--;
                }
            cout<<a<<endl;
        }
}
```

So how do u guys think that this code (for eg) can be edited for better compilation time?

Comment: I doubt this took much time at all to *compile*, I think you're concerned about *runtime*

Comment: no actually the compilation time @CoryKramer ... it will be useful if the code is submitted somewhere it is ranked by compilation time.

Comment: Reducing the compilation time of a one file program that fits in <30 lines is just silly IMO.

Comment: You definitely have *compilation time* and *runtime* backwards. Compile time would be the amount of time it takes for you to click compile and be ready to run. Runtime is how long it would take for your program to *execute and finish*. A site that ranks programs by speed goes by runtime (how long it took to complete the code)

Comment: Compilation time is basically a function of the size of the source code, including all the include files that are used, as well as the design of the compiler. Disabling optimizations will also speed up compilation, but it will slow down running the program.

Comment: @DrZoo Maybe he's confusing the words compilation and *computation* ?

Comment: Please explain what your program does so we can further help you

Comment: Thnaks @DrZoo for explaining... So how can we reduce the runtime using classes , structures , call by value , call by reference??????

Comment: Secondly this program is so small that running things in parallel would not be worth the time and there would be very little, if any, reasonable increase in speed. Since you do show interest in the idea of parallel computing, you can look into *OpenMP*

Comment: The only way to (meaningfully)reduce the runtime is to improve the algorithm.

Comment: Getting rid of the `for` loop is likely to be the best way to speed it up. I suspect there's a formula that can calculate the value of `a` without looping.

Comment: @Borgleader yeah you're probably right :)

Comment: Hint: `1+2+3+...+n` can be calculated as `n*(n+1)/2`

Comment: Anyhow, since the code is apparently working as intended, I think it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot for actually responding guys ... i chose this programme cause u know it was small and easy to assess . @DonLarynx just see the link once u'll understand its any easy question for advanced coders such as u.

Comment: Since it's now clear this is an "optimize my algorithm" question, I'm voting to close as **too broad**.  There were unusual past posts from this user - I hope he takes the time to read any close reasons he may come across.

Comment: @DrZoo some more input of your will be very much appreciated.

Comment: @DrewDormann i am really trying to understand something . and this place i thought will have been most helpful.

Comment: @Tejasbedi I hope it can help you - I think there may be a hurdle for you regarding either English language usage or organizing your questions into a clear presentation.  I wish you much success!

Comment: @Tejasbedi you can look at my profile. I posted my e-mail for communication. I'll take it down within an hour or so.

Comment: @Tejasbedi for example, you may want to [edit] this question so the title is not completely wrong and misleading.

Comment: First profile.  Second, turn up optimizations levels on you compiler.  Thirdly, replace your `for` loop with multiplication / algebra.  For example, the line `a+=N` is the fundamental basis for multiplication (repetitive addition), and the loop can be replaced by `a += j * N; N -= j;`

Comment: thanks everyone for your inputs .. My question may be wrong but atleast  i learn't something new and help full.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First profile.

Second, turn up optimizations levels on you compiler.

Thirdly, replace your for loop with multiplication / algebra. For example, the line
 `a+=N`
 is the fundamental basis for multiplication (repetitive addition), and the loop can be replaced by:
 `a += j * N; N -= j;`

Replacing the loop will speed up your program (if your compiler hasn't already replaced the loop).

Printing the assembly language for the function will show how the compiler applied optimizations.

**Edit 1:** 
Less code means a faster *build* time as well.  I don't know if time difference in building is measurable.